# Windows 8/10 desktop - how to change default view?

Tags: windows-10

How can I change the default 'medium-icon'-like view (icon over label) to a more compact 'list'-like view (icon to the left of label)?  I used to use the Pitaschio on Windows XP but I've not found a way to accomplish the task on Windows 8/10.

Comment: A screenshot would help

Comment: Do you mean in a File Explorer window, or on the desktop? Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: @ben n - Between my original post title/body + follow up posts I think it's pretty clear this discussion thread has nothing to do with File Explorer layout issues.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I'm not sure what you're after. Could you please provide a screenshot as Ramhound suggested?

Answer (score 0):

To set "List" view for desktop, click on the desktop and press:

> Ctrl + Shift + 5

For other view types:

```
Ctrl + Shift + 1    (Extra large icons)
Ctrl + Shift + 2    (Large icons)
Ctrl + Shift + 3    (Medium icons)
Ctrl + Shift + 4    (Small icons)
Ctrl + Shift + 5    (List)
Ctrl + Shift + 6    (Details)
Ctrl + Shift + 7    (Tiles)
```

([Desktop icon views - keyboard shortcuts](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-icons-tiles-view-mode-fix/))

Comment: After rebooting, the desktop list view is oriented horizontally, rather than vertically and I can't figure out how to fix this. Suggestions? (I'm running windows 8.1).  The other views (icons, etc.) work correctly.

Comment: Is there a screenshot you can upload?

Comment: Per your request: Instead of displaying the desktop in a left-justified vertical orientation, the desktop items are displayed horizontally across the top of the screen. I'll F/UP with a screenshot, although I'm not sure how much value it brings...

Comment: I think I get your point. In the linked article above, see if the steps listed in "Using the Registry Editor" helps. Or you may try clearing the mentioned key after export it to a file. Logoff and login back. Then try Ctrl + Shift + 5 again.

Comment: Screenshot: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14073903872395188482

Comment: Thx. Pls try my previous suggn. Let's know if that works.

Comment: @wsh32 Killing Explorer + REGEDIT + Start Explorer + CNT-SHIFT-5 results is correct horizontal layout but only temporarily - until Explorer is stopped (whether manually or via system reboot/shutdown).  My guess is that there are probably additional registry settings besides the LogicalViewMode and Mode settings in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop that are causing this behavior.

Comment: Does clearing the entire key (Bags\1\Desktop) and restarting the shell help? If that doesn't do it, you may try wiping out the entire folder views using the method or script here. http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-folder-views-bags-windows/

Comment: Searched registry for ListViewMode and found hundreds of entries in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags - far more than the sum total of CNTL-SHIFT-# combinations I could have entered into my system.  The ListViewMode and Mode fields have different values with no discernable pattern.

Comment: Workaround script:

Comment: I created a short CMD script as a workaround to 1. Kill Explorer.exe 2. Apply exported REG file from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop 3. Restart Explorer.exe